# How to use multiple Router with Backbones.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes, backbone.js, asset-pipeline

I want to use Backbones.js with my rails 3.1 (with assets) application and I would like to create a model independently to the collection without any url option in my model and I can't synchronize it with my server.
Is there any proper way to do? I can't find any tutorial using multiple routes.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're trying to ask here. Could you rephrase?

Comment: In fact I want to synchronize several objects in client side but using rails-backbone gem it create a router for each models and I want to switch my router and get only one model.
For exemple:
I have a route to get a list of posts, so i fetch all my posts and I want to get the author so I have to fetch only one model for my author and I have a model, a collection and a router for my posts and the same for my authors and i just whant to get my author when I am in the posts

Answer (score 2):

From the github page:
https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails

```
window.router = new Blog.Routers.PostsRouter({posts: <%= @posts.to_json.html_safe -%>});
```

so then if your needed access to Authors, you could do something like this:

```
window.AuthorRouter = new Blog.Routers.AuthorsRouter({authors: <%= @authors.to_json.html_safe -%>});
```

Having multiple routers shouldn't conflict.

Than you could access your Author Models from your PostsRouter:

```
AuthorRouter.AuthorView.model
```